# Randomized color splash code JS no library

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to create a color splash canoon, something like like throwing on a paper by a painter. When you look at the [Codepen](https://codepen.io/Figario/pen/vYjRxBr) example you can see the effect(click on the top left for the splash). As you can see it's not very good cause we see the particles movement. I would like to have the splash shape more randomized(with bezier curves?) and maybe achieve bigger splashes when holding the mouseclick longer.

I started to rebuild the code into a React TS app. I declared my types in an interface. To interact with an element of the DOM from within a React component, I use ref hooks API so ref.current holds a reference to canvas DOM node.

Then I added useEffect callback to interact directly with canvas in the DOM.

```
import React from "react";
import { useRef } from "react";
import { useEffect } from "react";

export interface Props {
  canvas: HTMLCanvasElement;
  context: CanvasRenderingContext2D;
  particles: [];
  x: number[];
  y: number[];
}

function App(props: Props) {
  //instead of getElement, I use useEffect
  //props.canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  //var ctx = props.canvas.getContext("2d");

  //Adjust the scaling of canvas depending on pixel density
  const getPixelRatio = (context) => {
    var backingStore =
      context.backingStorePixelRatio ||
      context.webkitBackingStorePixelRatio ||
      context.mozBackingStorePixelRatio ||
      context.msBackingStorePixelRatio ||
      context.oBackingStorePixelRatio ||
      context.backingStorePixelRatio ||
      1;

    return (window.devicePixelRatio || 1) / backingStore;
  };

  //ref to hold a reference to the canvas DOM node
  let ref = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    let canvas = ref.current;
    const size = props.canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    const dpr = window.devicePixelRatio || 1;
    props.canvas.height = size.height * dpr;
    props.canvas.width = size.width * dpr;

    let context = props.canvas.getContext("2d");
    props.context.scale(dpr, dpr);

    let ratio = getPixelRatio(context);
    var p = props.particles[i];

    props.context.beginPath();
    props.context.arc(p.x, p.y, p.size, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
    props.context.fill();
  });

  context.fillStyle = "black";

  props.particles = [];

  props.canvas.onmousedown = function (e: any) {
    for (var i = 0; i < 36 * 2; i++) {
      props.particles.push({
        x: e.clientX,
        y: e.clientY,
        angle: i * 5,
        size: 5 + Math.random() * 3,
        life: 200 + Math.random() * 50,
      });
    }
  };

  props.canvas.onmouseup = function () {
    //ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 600, 600);
  };

  var delta = 0;
  var last = Date.now();

  const animate = () => {
    delta = Date.now() - last;
    last = Date.now();
    for (var i = 0; i < props.particles.length; i++) {
      var p = props.particles[i];
      p.x += Math.cos(p.angle) * 4 + Math.random() * 2 - Math.random() * 2;
      p.y += Math.sin(p.angle) * 4 + Math.random() * 2 - Math.random() * 2;
      p.life -= delta;
      p.size -= delta / 50;

      if (p.size <= 0) {
        p.life = 0;
      }

      if (p.life <= 0) {
        props.particles.splice(i--, 1);
        continue;
      }
    }
  };

  //randomize the color
  const randomColorSet = () => {
    const colorRanges = [
      ["#FE7E9C", "#ff80df"],
      ["#93f", "#ff80df"],
      ["#d8dadb", "#53ceef"],
      ["#FE7E9C", "#F7BD8D"],
    ];
    return colorRanges[
      Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215 * colorRanges.length)
    ];
  };

  //set random color gradient
  const createHex = () => {
    var hexCode1 = "";
    var hexValues1 = "0123456789abcdef";

    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
      hexCode1 += hexValues1.charAt(
        Math.floor(Math.random() * hexValues1.length)
      );
    }
    return hexCode1;
  };

  const generate = () => {
    var deg = Math.floor(Math.random() * 360);

    var gradient =
      "linear-gradient(" +
      deg +
      "deg, " +
      "#" +
      createHex() +
      ", " +
      "#" +
      createHex() +
      ")";

    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = gradient;
    document.getElementById("bg").style.background = gradient;

    console.log(hexCode1, hexCode2);
  };
  document.onload = generate();


  const render = () => {
    context.fillStyle = randomColorSet;
    for (var i = 0; i < props.particles.length; i++) {
      if (Math.random() < 0.1) {
        continue;
      }

      //this part already happens in my useffect
      var p = props.particles[i];
      context.beginPath();
      context.arc(p.x, p.y, p.size, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
      context.fill();
    }
  };

  const animloop = () => {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(animloop);
    animate();
    render();
  };

  return (
    <canvas
      ref={ref}
      id="canvas"
      style={{ width: "100px", height: "100px" }}
    ></canvas>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Now even when I add everywhere any as type to test the functionality I cant get it run?

Comment: "I cant get it run" doesn't quite cut it. What do you mean with that? Does something happen that shouldn't? Does something not happen that should? Is there an error?

Comment: By the way, "adding everywhere any" will make your code _worse_, and more likely to not actually work.

Comment: Yes of course you are right, I did not intend to use any as solution. Simply as a test if it works and then would continue to try to assign the correct types to remove any. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So um, your reworking unfortunately doesn't make much sense.

Here's a version based on it that has strict types everywhere and works. It implements the particle logic as a custom hook `useSplash`, so the user just supplies a ref to a canvas and it does the rest. `useInterval` is supplied by the `use-interval` library, but you could use an alternative, of course.

You can find [a live demo here on CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/splash-gf7o1m?file=/src/App.tsx).

```
import React from "react";
import useInterval from "use-interval";

interface Particle {
  x: number;
  y: number;
  size: number;
  color: string;
  life: number;
  angle: number;
}

const colors = [
  "#FE7E9C",
  "#ff80df",
  "#93f",
  "#ff80df",
  "#d8dadb",
  "#53ceef",
  "#FE7E9C",
  "#F7BD8D"
];

function simulate(particles: readonly Particle[], delta: number): Particle[] {
  const newParticles: Particle[] = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < particles.length; i++) {
    var p: Particle = { ...particles[i] };
    p.x += Math.cos(p.angle) * 4 + Math.random() * 2 - Math.random() * 2;
    p.y += Math.sin(p.angle) * 4 + Math.random() * 2 - Math.random() * 2;
    p.life -= delta;
    p.size -= delta / 50;

    if (p.size <= 0) {
      p.life = 0;
    }

    if (p.life > 0) {
      newParticles.push(p);
    }
  }
  return newParticles;
}

function render(
  context: CanvasRenderingContext2D,
  particles: readonly Particle[]
) {
  for (var i = 0; i < particles.length; i++) {
    if (Math.random() < 0.1) {
      continue;
    }

    var p = particles[i];
    context.fillStyle = p.color;
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(p.x, p.y, p.size, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
    context.fill();
  }
}

function useSplash(canvasRef: React.RefObject<HTMLCanvasElement>) {
  const particlesRef = React.useRef<Particle[]>([]);
  const lastTimeRef = React.useRef<number>();

  const step = React.useCallback(
    (timestamp: number) => {
      if (!canvasRef.current) {
        return;
      }
      const context = canvasRef.current.getContext("2d");
      if (!context) {
        return;
      }
      if (!lastTimeRef.current) {
        lastTimeRef.current = timestamp;
      }
      const elapsed = timestamp - lastTimeRef.current;
      lastTimeRef.current = timestamp;
      if (particlesRef.current.length) {
        particlesRef.current = simulate(particlesRef.current, elapsed);
        render(context, particlesRef.current);
      }
    },
    [canvasRef]
  );
  useInterval(() => {
    step(Date.now());
  }, 1000 / 60);

  const createSplash = React.useCallback((x: number, y: number) => {
    const newParticles: Particle[] = [];
    const color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
    for (var i = 0; i < 36 * 2; i++) {
      newParticles.push({
        x,
        y,
        angle: i * 5,
        size: 5 + Math.random() * 3,
        life: 200 + Math.random() * 50,
        color
      });
    }
    particlesRef.current = [...particlesRef.current, ...newParticles];
  }, []);

  return { createSplash };
}

export default function App() {
  const canvasRef = React.useRef<HTMLCanvasElement>(null);
  const { createSplash } = useSplash(canvasRef);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <canvas
        ref={canvasRef}
        width={400}
        height={400}
        onMouseDown={(e) => createSplash(e.clientX, e.clientY)}
        style={{ border: "1px solid orange" }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Great answer.  Canvas manipulation code always sucks in React but refs are definitely the correct way.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I studies your solution and think I have no further questions